# Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect

Tags: php, laravel

When I run the below API I got this error

> "Indirect modification of overloaded property App\User::$attendance has no effect".

I still cannot figure it out for so long. Could you please someone help me on this.

```
public function apiPresent( $id, Request $request )
{
    $tokenuser = User::with('attendance')
                    ->where('token', $request->input('token'))->first();
    $present   = $request->input('present');
    $user      = User::with('attendance')->find($id);

    if( $user && $tokenuser == $user )
    {
        $user->attendance->present = $present;
        $user->attendance->date    = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
        $user->attendance->time    = Carbon::now()->format('H-i');
        $user->attendance->save();

        return response()->json([
                    'status'  => 'Ok',
                    'message' => 'Present Changed',
                    'Present' => $user->attendance->present
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json([
                    'status'  => 'Fail',
                    'message' => 'Your state does not changed'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: which type of eloquent relationship is there hasMany or belongsto?? in User::with('attendance')

Comment: @kunal >> In User Model, I use this 
 'public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Attendance');
    }'
and in the attendance model, i use 
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

Comment: i think you need to save in different way this is wrong way you are doing @Htoo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If i understand your problem. You are saving the attendance.

Try this:

```
use App\Attendance; // Add before controller declaration

public function apiPresent( $id, Request $request )
{
    $tokenuser = User::where('token', $request->input('token'))->first();
    $present   = $request->input('present');
    $user      = User::find($id);

    if( $user && $tokenuser->id == $user->id ){
        $attendance = new Attendance;
        $attendance->present = $present;
        $attendance->date    = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
        $attendance->time    = Carbon::now()->format('H-i');
        $attendance->save();

        return response()->json([
                'status'  => 'Ok',
                'message' => 'Present Changed',
                'Present' => $present
       ]);
    }
    else {
        return response()->json([
                'status'  => 'Fail',
                'message' => 'Your state does not changed'
       ]);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works for me like magic !! thanks bro ! you help made my day !

Comment: can you shed light on what the issue was though? Was it use the `use` statement?  And why didn't OP add a point to this?

Comment: I downvoted this as this didn't highlighted what the fix was and where it all went wrong

Comment: @kunal How did that work? You just made a new instance of  Attendance and didn't tight it to the User object.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're trying to directly assign to a relation of `App::User`. Your code segment highlights this:

```
if( $user && $tokenuser->id == $user->id ){
    $user->attendance->present = $present;
    $user->attendance->date    = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
    $user->attendance->time    = Carbon::now()->format('H-i');
    $user->attendance->save();
    ...
```

In Eloquent, you access a relation as a property using the magic [__get()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) method, which returns a **copy** of the object.

When you're trying to assign any value to any of the relation's property (in this case **$user->attendance**), it will not have any effect on the original object at all, hence the warning.

You can fix this by creating new object instance and add it to `create` method, like this:

```
$attendance = new Attendance();
$attendance->present = $present;
$attendance->date    = Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y');
$attendance->time    = Carbon::now()->format('H-i');
$user->attendance->create($attendance);
```

This will save the new record with the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

Laravel php 5.7 & Mysql 5.7 
The Error which i got for the following code is **Indirect modification of overloaded property Illuminate\Http\Request::${**

Error code

```
 $config->name = $request->title;
        $config->lead_by_id = $request->owner;
        $config->tech_stack = $request->stack;
        $config->is_POC = $request->
        $config->updated_by = $request->
        $config->start_date = $request->start_date;
        $config->end_date = $request->end_date;
```

Then i found that i have not set the request variable properly

Fix

```
 $config->name = $request->title;
        $config->lead_by_id = $request->owner;
        $config->tech_stack = $request->stack;
        $config->is_POC = $request->poc;
        $config->updated_by = $request->$user->id;
        $config->start_date = $request->start_date;
        $config->end_date = $request->end_date;
```